# Convert datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, date-formatting

How can i convert the datetime format below

**2010-10-25 11:13:36.700**

into

**25-Oct-2010** or **2010-10-25 00:00:00.000**

Comment: It's not hard to do via the CONVERT() function, but it's almost always _better_ to do it in application code rather than sql.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: That's assuming this is for presentation only.  Date manipulation might be necessary for a GROUP BY or ORDER BY....

Comment: The last example, is that supposed to be *2010* -10-25 00:00:00.000 instead of *2009* ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### To get "25-Oct-2010"

Assuming the value is supplied as a string, not a DATETIME data type:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST('2010-10-25 11:13:36.700' AS DATETIME), 106), ' ', '-')
```

See the [CAST/CONVERT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for other formats, though the one you requested requires post-processing.

### To get "2010-10-25 00:00:00.000"

The best performing means is to use DATEADD & DATEDIFF:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, '2010-10-25 11:13:36.700'), 0)
```

References:

- [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

### Testing

```
WITH sample AS (
   SELECT CAST('2010-10-25 11:13:36.700' AS DATETIME) dt)
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, s.dt, 106), ' ', '-') AS col1,
       DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, s.dt), 0) AS col2
  FROM sample s
```

Returns:

```
col1          col2
-------------------------------------
25-Oct-2010   2010-10-25 00:00:00.000
```

## Addendum

Being that you're on SQL Server 2005, you could make date formatting easier for yourself by creating a SQLCLR function that would allow you to use the .NET date formatting.

Answer (score 2):

check this one

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR, getdate(),106)
```

this will give you `25 Oct 2010`

AND

```
SELECT REPLACE(convert(VARCHAR, getdate(),106), ' ' , '-')
```

this will give you `25-Oct-2010`

Answer (score 1):

Check if this can help you:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-')
```

You can get more info [Here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

PD. Stackoverflow can be too addicted sometimes, you might wanna try google before

Answer (score 1):

select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),getDATE(),105)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1)   --12/30/06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 2)   --06.12.30
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 3)   --30/12/06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 4)   --30.12.06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 5)   --30-12-06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 6)   --30 Dec 06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 7)   --Dec 30, 06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 10)  --12-30-06
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 11)  --06/12/30
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 12)  --061230
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 23)  --2006-12-30
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) --12/30/2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 102) --2006.12.30
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) --30/12/2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 104) --30.12.2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 105) --30-12-2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 106) --30 Dec 2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 107) --Dec 30, 2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 110) --12-30-2006
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 111) --2006/12/30
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) --20061230
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: Output shown in right side and how it does. for more details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15